# log4net saving errors to db, getting nulls in parameters

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, log4net

I am getting null values in Environment, ApplicationName, ApplicationPath, ExceptionData when inserting rows in a SQL Server 2005 DB.

My log4net configuration is as follows:

```xml
<log4net>
  <appender name="ADONetAppender_SqlServer" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;User Id=xxx;Password=xx;Connection Timeout=200;" />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO [ApplicationLog] ([TimeStamp],[SeverityLevel],[LoggerName],[Environment],[ApplicationName],[ApplicationPath],[ServerName],[Message],[ExceptionData]) VALUES (@TimeStamp,@SeverityLevel,@LoggerName,@Environment,@ApplicationName,@ApplicationPath,@ServerName,@Message,@ExceptionData)" />
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@TimeStamp" />
      <dbType value="DateTime" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@SeverityLevel" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="10" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@LoggerName" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@Environment" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="-1" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{EnvironmentName}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@ApplicationName" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="128" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{AppName}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@ApplicationPath" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{AppPath}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@ServerName" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{log4net:HostName}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@Message" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="-1" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@ExceptionData" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="-1" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{exceptionDetails}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
</appender>
<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
  <to value="xxx" />
  <from value="xxx" />
  <subject value="(Error) xxx" />
  <smtpHost value="xxx" />
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <lossy value="false" />
  <threshold value="ERROR" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%utcdate [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{log4net:HostName}] - %message%newline%newlineException details:%newline%property{exceptionDetails}" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<root>
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="ADONetAppender_SqlServer" />
  <appender-ref ref="SmtpAppender" />
</root>
```

In the global.asax, Application_Error, I call log4net to configure, and then log the exception as follows:

```
Dim ex As New Exception
ex = Server.GetLastError      

log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()
log.Logger.Log(ex.Source.GetType, log4net.Core.Level.Fatal, ex.StackTrace, ex)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not explicitly said otherwise or shown how you initialise them, I am guessing you think that Environment, ApplicationName, ApplicationPath and ExceptionData are pre-defined properties which I don't think is true.

So, if you want to use these properties, then somewhere in your code, you need to set these properties to the values you want. Eg

```
 log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["AppName"] = "...";
```

or

```
 log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["exceptionDetails] = "...";
```

Some of the variables could be global to your application and hence could be set once, but  exceptiondetails should be set just prior to calling log.Logger.Log and should use the ThreadContext rather than GlobalContext.

[See here for more information on the various contexts](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html)

Note, there are some [pre defined patterns](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html)  which you may be able to use instead. For example %exception or %appdomain